# Use countifs with two different date formats

Tags: excel, excel-formula, format, countif

I have a workbook in excel which contains two sheets: called Daily and daily_07

in Daily I have a column starting from A3:A with the dates of this month.
In B1:H1 I have the names of some agents

In my daily_07 worksheet I have a list of agents which logged some tickets at different dates
The dates are in Column A:A and the agent names are in column B:B

My goal is to count the dates per Agent
This is my formula in cell B3 to do it:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("daily_" & TEXT($A3; "mm") & "!$A:$A"); $A3; INDIRECT("daily_" & TEXT($A3; "mm") & "!$B:$B"); B$1)
```

the indirect function for daily_07 is used because when I change the month it will take the correct sheet for example, selecting the month june is reffering to daily_06

it works fine if the date formats are the same but the problem is that the date format in sheet daily_07 for an example is set to: d/mm/jjjj u:mm

An I cannot compare it to the date format: dd/mm/yyyy which seems logic because they don't have the same value  but how can I add this to the formula?

I'd really appreciate some help. (i'm not a master in excel)

Comment: Found the solution: 

=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Daily_" & TEXT($A8; "mm") & TEXT( "!$A:$A";"dd/mm-jjjj")); ">=" & INT($A8);INDIRECT("Daily_" & TEXT($A8; "mm") & TEXT( "!$A:$A";"dd/mm-jjjj")); "<=" & INT($A8)+1; INDIRECT("Daily_" & TEXT($A8; "mm") & "!$B:$B"); B$1)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Daily_" & TEXT($A8; "mm") & TEXT( "!$A:$A";"dd/mm-jjjj")); ">=" & INT($A8);INDIRECT("Daily_" & TEXT($A8; "mm") & TEXT( "!$A:$A";"dd/mm-jjjj")); "<=" & INT($A8)+1; INDIRECT("Daily_" & TEXT($A8; "mm") & "!$B:$B"); B$1)
```

By using the dates in column A in daily_07 I can use the greater than or equal to extract from A3
the dates in column A of the daily_07  sheet are less than the day after the extracted ate from A3

at least we can can see if the values of column b of the daily_07 are equal to the value in B1